# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Anybody know what's wrong with my code?  I am using a simple INSERT statement (as opposed to the regular PreparedStatement because I am trying to utilize mySQL's AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT functions.  I do not know how to use them with the regular set up of the PreparedStatements. with all the funky question marks.

I keep getting the classic:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`video_game_db`.`login`, CONSTRAINT `login_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cust_ID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`cust_ID`))

Of course, it's driving me batty.

I spent all night trying to make the regular JDBC implementation of the cipher "stuff" work.  In the end, I could only encrypt the strings, but could not decrypt them.  I figured it had to do something with mySQL as opposed to JDBC, as before I input them into the database they decrypted fine, but afterwards I could get it to work.

---

Please take a look at my JDBC table DDL and DML statements below:

**DDL**

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE customer("+"cust_ID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,"+"PRIMARY KEY(cust_ID),"+"first_Name CHAR(30)NOT NULL,mI CHAR(2),last_Name CHAR(50)NOT NULL,street_Name CHAR(50),city CHAR(30) NOT NULL,state CHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
            +"zip_Code CHAR(5) NOT NULL, home_Phone CHAR(12) UNIQUE, referrer CHAR(30), quantity INTEGER NOT NULL, item_No CHAR(10))"); 
s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE login ("+"user_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,"+"PRIMARY KEY(user_Name),"+"pass_Word CHAR(50)NOT NULL, cust_ID CHAR(10))");
```

**DML**

```
public static void setCustTable(String cust_ID, String lName, String fName, String mI, String street_Name, String city, String state,
  String zip_Code, String home_Phone, String referrer, int quantity, String itemNo)throws IOException, SQLException 
{

// connect to database
try
{    

    PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer (cust_ID, first_Name, mI, last_Name, street_Name, city, state, zip_Code, home_Phone, referrer, quantity, item_No)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    stat.setString(1, cust_ID);
    stat.setString(2, fName);
    stat.setString(3, mI);
    stat.setString(4, lName);
    stat.setString(5, street_Name);
    stat.setString(6, city);
    stat.setString(7, state);
    stat.setString(8, zip_Code);
    stat.setString(9, home_Phone);
    stat.setString(10, referrer);
    stat.setInt(11, quantity);
    stat.setString(12, itemNo);

    stat.executeUpdate();
}  

 catch (SQLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}

**********************************************************************************



public static void insertLoginData(String username5, String password5, String custID5)throws IOException, SQLException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException

{
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    String insert="INSERT INTO login VALUES('username5', AES_ENCRYPT('text','password5'),'custID5')";
    s.executeUpdate(insert);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it worth, I don't see any insert into `customer`. Error message tells that there is a foreign key constraint from login to
customer. So customer entry must exist prior to login insert.

---

Was there intention to quote 'username5'? I think it is a parameter to method but insert uses literal.

Comment: Customer is already populated.  I just was trying to keep the code short for you guys.  I will add it in just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Ironically, I was able to use the PreparedStatement in JDBC and the customer insert statement works like a charm. . . is there a workaround for the apparent inconsistency between JDBC and mySQL when it comes to encryption?  There has got to be.  I got a book on CoreJava and all it does is show me how to encrypt files?  What use is that is you are trying to encrypt passwords. . . Ok. . .sorry. . . just frustrated.  Haven't slept more than 3 hours a night working on this dang project . . sorry about the rant. . .

Comment: @Mike: Does customer population happen in the same transaction as login? If the transactions are separate, is the one where customer is inserted, already committed by the time transaction for login insertion starts?

Comment: Yes, the customer table is populated right before the login table is populated.

Comment: @Mike what I suggest to try for debugging is to put select query right before login insert and use the same variable for cust_ID in both.

Comment: @Mike Did you intend to quote 'username5'? You are passing a literal.

Comment: If I don't leave the quote in there is gives me the error: Unknown column 'username5' in 'field list' error.

Comment: My tab does not show code well, so I will look again when I get to normal pc. In the meantime, I still think that may be it should be `cust_ID` and not `'username5'`?

Comment: You know. . . I am a moron. . . I have to put plus (+) before my variables in order for the correct values to come through into my statements . . . let's hope that does it. . .

Comment: @Mike yep I see now. The string is not concatenated. Mysql was right after all about constraint violation :)

Comment: So. . . now how do i get rid of the following error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'javanut' in 'field list'

Comment: javanut is the value of my username5 variable.

Comment: I will post another question.  Thanks for your help Alex.